# NSPredicate versus NSString: Which is better/faster for finding superstrings?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, nspredicate

I have a large number of strings that I'm searching to see if a given substring exists. It seems there are two reasonable ways to do this.

Option 1: Use the `NSString` method `rangeOfSubstring` and test whether `.location` exists:

```
NSRange range = [string rangeOfSubstring:substring];
return (range.location != NSNotFound);
```

Option 2. Use the `NSPredicate` syntax `CONTAINS`:

```
NSPredicate *regex = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS %@", substring];
return ([regex evaluateWithObject:string] == YES)
```

Which method is better, or is there a good Option 3 that I'm completely missing? No, I'm not sure exactly what I mean by "better", but possibly I mean faster when iterated over many, many `string`s.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should benchmark and time any solution that uses `NSPredicate` because in my experience `NSPredicate` can be very slow.

For simplicity, I would go with a simple `for(NSString *string in stringsArray) { }` type of loop.  The loop body would contain a simple `rangeOfSubstring` check.  You might be able improve the performance of this by a few percent by using [`CFStringFind()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringFind), but you'll only see a benefit if you're searching through lots of strings.  The advantage to using `CFStringFind()` is that you can avoid the (very small) Objective-C message dispatch overhead.  Again, it's usually only a win to switch to that when you're search "a lot" of strings (for some always changing value of "a lot"), and you should always benchmark to be sure.  Prefer the simpler Objective-C `rangeOfString:` way if you can.

A much more complicated approach is to use the ^Blocks feature with the `NSEnumerationConcurrent` option.  `NSEnumerationConcurrent` is only a hint that you'd like the enumeration to happen concurrently if possible, and an implementation is free to ignore this hint if it can't support concurrent enumeration.  However, your standard `NSArray` is most likely going to implement concurrent enumeration.  In practice, this has the effect of dividing up all the objects in the `NSArray` and splitting them across the available CPU's.  You need to be careful about how to mutate state and objects that is accessed by the ^Block across multiple threads.  Here's one potential way of doing it:

```
// Be sure to #include <libkern/OSAtomic.h>

__block volatile OSSpinLock spinLock = OS_SPINLOCK_INIT;
__block NSMutableArray *matchesArray = [NSMutableArray array];

[stringsToSearchArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSRange matchedRange = [obj rangeOfString:@"this"];
    if(matchedRange.location != NSNotFound) {
      OSSpinLockLock((volatile OSSpinLock * volatile)&spinLock);
      [matchesArray addObject:obj];
      OSSpinLockUnlock((volatile OSSpinLock * volatile)&spinLock);
    }
  }];

// At this point, matchesArray will contain all the strings that had a match.
```

This uses a lightweight `OSSpinLock` to make sure only one thread has access to and updates `matchesArray` at a time.  You can use the same `CFStringFind()` suggestion from above here as well.

Also, you should be aware that `rangeOfString:` won't, by itself, match on "word boundaries".  In the example above, I used the word `this`, which would match the string `A paleolithist walked in to the bar...` even though it does not contain the word `this`.

The simplest solution to this little wrinkle is to use an ICU regular expression and take advantage of it's "enhanced word breaking" functionality.  To do this, you have a few options:

- `NSRegularExpression`, currently only available on >4.2 or >4.3 iOS (I forget which).
- [RegexKit*Lite*](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/index.html), via [RegexKitLite-4.0.tar.bz2](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/regexkit/RegexKitLite-4.0.tar.bz2)
- `NSPredicate`, via `SELF MATCHES '(?w)\b...\b'`.  The advantage to this is that it requires nothing extra (i.e., RegexKit*Lite*) and is available on all(?) versions of Mac OS X, and iOS > 3.0.

The following code shows how to use the enhanced word breaking functionality in ICU regular expressions via `NSPredicate`:

```
NSString *searchForString = @"this";
NSString *regexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".*(?w:\\b\\Q%@\\E\\b).*", searchForString];
NSPredicate *wordBoundaryRegexPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regexString];
NSArray *matchesArray = [stringsToSearchArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:wordBoundaryRegexPredicate];
```

You can make the search case insensitive by replacing the `(?w:` in `regexString` with `(?wi:`.

The regex, if you're interested, basically says

- `.*(?w:...).*` says "match anything up to and after the `(?w:...)` part" (i.e., we're only interested in the `(?w:...)` part).
- `(?w:...)` says "Turn on the ICU enhanced word breaking / finding feature inside the parenthesis".
- `\\b...\\b` (which is really only a single backslash, any backslash has to be backslash escaped when it's inside a `@""` string) says "Match at a word boundary".
- `\\Q...\\E` says "Treat the text starting immediately after `\Q` and up to `\E` as literal text (think "Quote" and "End")".  In other words, any characters in the "quoted literal text" do not have their special regex meaning.

The reason for the `\Q...\E` is that you probably want to match the literal characters in `searchForString`.  Without this, `searchForString` would be treated as part of the regex. As an example, if `searchForString` was `this?`, then without `\Q...\E` it would ***not*** match the literal string `this?`, but either `thi` or `this`, which is probably not what you want.  :)

Comment: The `(?w:…)` part was what I needed to make the `\\b`’s work. Many thanks!

Comment: Great answer! [How do I benchmark in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610687/core-data-performance-nspredicate-comparing-objects)

Answer (score 2):

**Case (n):** If you are having *array of strings* to test for a sub string, it will be better to use `NSPredicate`.

```
NSPredicate *regex = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS %@", substring];
NSArray *resultArray = [originalArrayOfStrings filteredArrayUsingPredicate:regex];
```

This will return array of strings which contain the sub string.

If you use`NSRange`, in this case, you  need to loop through all the string objects of the array manually, and obviously it will be slower than `NSPredicate`.

Comment: I like this. I can plunk them into an array easily enough. I'll give it a test to see how well it performs. Thanks

Comment: Hi @PengOne, I've just posted the code to show you how to filter an array using `NSPredicate`. But, I myself feel that this may not the answer for your question. @johne's answer contains more context which your question deserves. I suggest you to review the answers again and wait for the correct answer if its not here already. :)