# Core Data Performance: NSPredicate comparing objects

Tags: performance, core-data, profile, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

If my `Author` `NSManagedObject` model has a `authorID` attribute (determined by the server), will an `NSFetchRequest` perform better if the `NSPredicate` filters by `authorID` rather than the complete `Author` object? Let's say I'm fetching all `Book` `NSManagedObject`s by a certain `author`. Which `predicateFormat` is better?

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"author = %@", anAuthor]
```

or

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"author.authorID = %@", anAuthor.authorID]
```

What's the best way to profile this? I have Core Data testing working with `OCUnit` (`SenTestingKit`). Does iOS have something like [Ruby's Benchmark module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html)?

Comment: Do you have the author object at hand when performing the fetch? If you were to use the Author object, I am assuming you'd need to first fetch it and then perform a second request for the books by that author (2 trips to the database). If you already have the id you can get the results you need with one fetch request.

Comment: This won't solve your issue but you better know that Apple Documentation states that you should use '==' and not just '=' when writing predicates.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth running your app with an argument of `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1`, as detailed [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html).

You could then see if Core Data was executing the same SQL in both circumstances (assuming you're using a SQLite store).

Answer (score 0):

The first one (using just `Author`) would probably be faster, but only testing will tell you for sure.

If you fetch (e.g. `Book`) objects that have an relationship to `Author` and you use a predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"author = %@", anAuthor]
```

SQLite can see if the merge table from `Book` to `Author` has the right primary key for that given `author`. In other words, the predicate turns into a check for the `Author` entities primary key. CoreData still has to consult the merge table, though.

If you use

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"author.authorID = %@", anAuthor.authorID]
```

then SQLite will have to `join` the merge table with the actual `Author` table and then match the resulting `authorID` column. That would be more work. And it would break down if `authorID` isn't indexed.

Comment: I came across this while debugging a similar predicate; I'm not able to get an object based predicate to work, using the same format you have in the first example. Inspecting the data directly in sqlite confirms that it isn't working. I'd like to know more, or understand why it may not be working

Comment: What does the SQL request look like? What kind of inspecting are you doing?