# Core Data search like iPhone Contacts app?

Tags: iphone, regex, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `Contact : NSManagedObject`. I want to search all contacts by `name` (full name). The search should perform like that of iPhone's Contacts app. So, `name` matches `searchString` if every word in `searchString` begins with any word in `name`. The search is case & diacritic insensitive.

E.g., `name` "Matt Di Pasquale" matches `searchString` "Matt Pa", "Matt Mat", and "Pasq Di má" but does not match "att" or "squale".

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Watch the [WWDC 2010 Session Video: Optimizing Core Data Performance on iPhone OS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=137) for a much faster way to do this.

Based on [another answer about NSPredicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6197273/242933), create an `NSCompoundPredicate` from subpredicates using an [ICU regular expression](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp):

```
NSArray *searchWords = [searchString words]; // see link below (1)
NSMutableArray *subpredicates = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[searchWords count]];
for (NSString *searchWord in searchWords) {
    [subpredicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                              @"name CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND" // maybe speeds it up
                              " name MATCHES[cd] %@",
                              searchWord, [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                           @".*\\b%@.*", searchWord]]];
}
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpredicates];
```

I think `MATCHES` filtering happens after the objects have been fetched into memory, so `name CONTAINS[cd] %@` should limit the number of fetched objects and perhaps speed things up.

(1) [Cocoa Plant implements `-[NSString words]`](https://github.com/acani/CocoaPlant/blob/master/CocoaPlant/NSString+CocoaPlant.m#L40-54)